# Eigenvectors of a tensor in $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, eigenvector, multilinear-algebra, tensor

I want to find the critical point of tensor $f=a_0b_0c_0 + a_1b_1c_1$ in $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$, and I followed this construction:

First, I take the following partial derivative:

With respect to $a$,  $\cfrac{\partial f }{\partial a_0}=b_0c_0, \cfrac{\partial f }{\partial a_1}=b_1c_1,$ and with respect to $b$,  $\cfrac{\partial f }{\partial b_0}=a_0c_0, \cfrac{\partial f }{\partial b_1}=a_1c_1,$ and with respect to $c$,  $\cfrac{\partial f }{\partial c_0}=a_0b_0, \ \ \cfrac{\partial f }{\partial c_1}=a_1b_1.$

Then I need to find $2 \times 2$-minors of the following matrices:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    b_0c_0 & b_1c_1  \\
    a_0 & a_1  \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_0c_0 & a_1c_1  \\
    b_0 & b_1  \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_0b_0 & a_1b_1  \\
    c_0 & c_1  \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
Then I have the following system of equation to solve:
\begin{equation*}
    \left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{3}
        % R & L   &  R & L   &  R & L 
        a_1b_0c_0 & - a_0b_1c_1   = 0 \\
        b_1a_0c_0 & - b_0a_1c_1   = 0 \\
        c_1a_0b_0 & - c_0a_1b_1   = 0
    \end{alignedat} \ ,
    \right.
    \end{equation*}
There are 6 variables and 3 equations, and by solving this system we get 23 group of solutions, then we have many infinite solutions, I am wondering if there is another way. Solution has the form:
$$(\alpha_0 a_0 + \alpha_1 a_1) \otimes (\beta_0 b_0 + \beta_1 b_1) \otimes (\gamma_0 c_0 + \gamma_1 c_1).$$

Comment: Please do not cross post [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123011/eigenvectors-of-a-tensor-in-mathbbc2-otimes-mathbbc2-otimes-mathbbc).

Comment: I have deleted the question on MSE, I thought MO is better place to ask. Thank you for your note.

Comment: Could you please define what exactly do you mean by a critical point in this context?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I have added some explanation.

Comment: Base points of the gradient are singular points of the hypersurface.

Comment: @ZachTeitler I know there is 6 critical points by (Friedland and Ottaviani Theorem). I am so close to it, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, it is much clearer now! And your last task is straightforward. The system$$\begin{align*}b_0c_0&=\alpha a_0\\b_1c_1&=\alpha a_1\\a_0c_0&=\beta b_0\\a_1c_1&=\beta b_1\\a_0b_0&=\gamma c_0\\a_1b_1&=\gamma c_1\end{align*}$$has in fact 23 solutions, but only six of them satisfy $(a_0,a_1),(b_0,b_1),(c_0,c_1)\ne(0,0)$. These are$$\begin{align*}&(1,0),(1,0),(1,0)\\&(0,1),(0,1),(0,1)\\&(1,1),(1,1),(1,1)\\&(1,1),(1,-1),(1,-1)\\&(1,-1),(1,1),(1,-1)\\&(1,-1),(1,-1),(1,1)\end{align*}$$

Comment: (Well, more precisely I should probably say$$\begin{align*}&a_0=b_0=c_0=0\\&a_1=b_1=c_1=0\\&a_1=a_0,b_1=b_0,c_1=c_0\\&a_1=a_0,b_1=-b_0,c_1=-c_0\\&a_1=-a_0,b_1=b_0,c_1=-c_0\\&a_1=-a_0,b_1=-b_0,c_1=c_0\end{align*}$$)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thank you for your answer. It is correct, I may ask you write it in answer then I can accept it. Another question how did you compute 23 solutions?

Comment: Well, frankly speaking, although I certainly find the initial question research level, but I think the final problem that you reduced it to yourself is an elementary algebra exercise, so I am in doubt whether its place is on this site after all. The 23 solutions were given by Mathematica in response to `Solve[{b0 c0==a a0,b1 c1==a a1,a0 c0==b b0,a1 c1==b b1,a0 b0==c c0,a1 b1==c c1}]` but I am sure it is easy to do it by hand, I just did it this way to ensure I do not miss anything.

Comment: Actually, since the reduction is probably not obvious, I may suggest this: you can write an answer yourself, moving the last part of the question (everything after **Recall**) to the answer and adding the solution in the end.

Comment: By the way, I also have a question. You begin that **Recall** part with "A Symmetric $n\times n\times n$ tensor like $T$..." and I don't quite understand this. A priori $T$ is just any tensor, not necessarily symmetric, is not it?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე you are right actually, I was solving the problem during edit the question, and I added it to the question, no need to be symmetric at all, I will edit the question again. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recall**. Consider a $d$-dimensional rectangular tensor $T$ in $\mathbb{K}^{n_1 \times \dots \times n_d}$. It corresponds to a multilinear form:
$$T=\sum_{i_1=1}^{n_1} \sum_{i_2=1}^{n_2} \dots \sum_{i_n=1}^{n_d} t_{i_1 \dots i_d}x_{i_1}x_{i_2} \dots x_{i_d}.$$
The **singular vector tuples** (critical points) of $T$ are the fixed points of the gradient
map $$\nabla T: \mathbb{P}^{{n_1}-1} \times \dots \mathbb{P}^{{n_d}-1} \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{{n_1}-1} \times \dots \mathbb{P}^{{n_d}-1}  .$$

$f$ is considered as a $2 \times 2 \times 2$-tensor. The gradient $\nabla f$ of this trilinear form is the rational map:
$$\nabla T: \mathbb{P}^{1} \times \mathbb{P}^{1} \times \mathbb{P}^{1}  \dashrightarrow \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \  \  \mathbb{P}^{1} \times \mathbb{P}^{1} \times \mathbb{P}^{1} $$
$$((a_0:a_1),(b_0:b_1),(c_0:c_1))  \mapsto  \ \ ((b_0c_0:b_1c_1),(a_0c_0:a_1c_1),(a_0b_0:a_1b_1)),$$
then we need to find fixed points of the map $\nabla T$. As we see in the question this leads us to the written system of equations, by solving it we get exactly $6$ solutions which lie on $\mathbb{P}^{1} \times \mathbb{P}^{1} \times \mathbb{P}^{1}$(**Segre variety**), it means $(a_0,a_1),(b_0,b_1),(c_0,c_1)\neq(0,0)$. The solutions are:
$$((1:0),(1:0),(1:0)), \  ((0:1),(0:1),(0:1)), \  ((1:1),(1:1),(1:1)), \  ((1:1),(1:−1),(1:−1)), \ ((1:−1),(1:1),(1:−1)), \ ((1:−1),(1:−1),(1:1)).$$

The expected number of singular vector triples is predicted by the following
theorem.

**Theorem.**[Friedland and Ottaviani] For a general $n_1 \times \dots \times n_d$-tensor $T$ over an
algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$, the number of singular vector tuples is the coefficient of the
monomial $z_{1}^{n_1-1} \dots z_{d}^{d_1-1}$ in the polynomial
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} \cfrac{\hat{z_i}^{n_i} - {z_i}^{n_i} }{\hat{z_i}-z_i},$$
where $\hat{z_i}=z_1+ \dots +z_{i-1}+z_{i+1}+ \dots + z_d.$
Here our case is $2 \times 2 \times 2$-tensors, so we will have 6 singular triples.